# What is the definition of derivation of tensor algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, nonassociative-algebras

Derivation $d$ of a Lie algebra $L$ is defined as $d([x,y])=[d(x),y]+[x,d(y)]$ for all $x,y \in L$. Let consider $T(L)$ be the tensor algebra and $S(L)$ be the symmetric algebra of $L$. How a derivation map on $T(L)$ is defined?

Comment: The tensor algebra is an associative algebra, and a derivation $D:A\rightarrow A$ of an associative algebra $A$ is a linear map satisfying the Leibniz rule, i.e., $D(xy)=D(x)y+xD(y)$. Of course, this definition also holds for non-associative algebras, in particular for Lie algebras, just rewrite $[x,y]=x\cdot y$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your answer. Does there exists a definition of antiderivation of associative algebras  similar to nonassociative algebras?

Comment: Yes, because nonassociative algebras inlcude associative algebras - the name only means "not necessarily associative algebras". So arbitrary $K$-algebras.

Comment: Might as well make that an answer @DietrichBurde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra, not necessarily associative, with $K$-bilinear product $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$. A *derivation* of $A$ is a $K$-linear map $D\colon A\rightarrow A$ satisfying the Leibniz rule
$$
D(x\cdot y)=D(x)\cdot y+x\cdot D(y)
$$
for all $x,y\in A$. The tensor algebra $A=T(V)$ is an associative algebra, so the definition also applies here. The space of all derivations of $A$ is denoted by ${\rm Der}(A)$. It forms a Lie subalgebra of the linear Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(A)$.